# How to authenticate an application using both Azure AD and Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, blazor-server-side

We have a Blazor Server web application. It is set to be authenticated with Azure AD, so our employees can sign in. But we need also to allow general public to register and sign in. So the user should be given a choice to login using either an individual account or work/school account. I registered the application with Azure B2C and got all the IDs that may be needed, but can't figure out what else needs to be done to make it work. Can you give me some reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should [federate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-azure-ad-single-tenant?pivots=b2c-user-flow) Azure AD and Azure AD B2C.

The flow is then:

- App. configured to B2C
- User gets the login page
- Login page has the ability to log in with local account or with a button that takes them to Azure AD
- User chooses flow they want

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have one issue though. When I try to create a user flow and then run it, my app name is not in the Application dropdown, even though it is registered with B2C directory. Could you tell what is missing?

Comment: I even changed the app registration, set supported account types to "multiple organizations". And yet the app does not show up in the dropdown.

Comment: Is the app. using OIDC? Did you create the app. in the B2C tenant rather than the associated AD tenant?

Comment: Figured out, thank you. I had wrong "Supported Account Types". Should be "All users".